# Changeable parameter file for Java program

Tags: java, parameters, jar, directory, artifact

I made a program for my employer, with one of the abilities being that non-software employees can change properties in several different parameter files. For example (something that isn't actually in the program), I put a "volume" parameter that the user can change in volume.txt.

However, it appears that when running the actual jar file, changing these values doesn't affect the program. Am I safe to assume that when I create the artifact, java builds the file into the jar file? I changed values for the parameter file in both source and the artifact production, but nothing changed. How should I fix this so that changes in the file will be read? Should I build the artifact without the files in the source folder and instead put them in the location of the executable jar? Thanks!

Comment: The JAR is what you run, but the config file which the the JAR _reads_ should be in some location which your users can actually edit.

Answer (score 0):

Properties files that can be edited by your users should be on a directory where your users have access to and where they cannot do much harm.

It is not clear in your question but i assume that the properties can be modified while your application is running. To detect file changes you can use a `java.nio.file.WatchService`.

I have created a small demo program for you. Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

public class Main {

    private static String WATCH_DIR = "c:/temp";
    private static String WATCH_FILE_NAME = "volume.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        try (final WatchService watchService = fileSystem.newWatchService()) {
            fileSystem.getPath(WATCH_DIR).register(watchService, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            while (true) {
                final WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    // "ENTRY_MODIFY" so context will be an instance of Path.
                    final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
                    if (changed.endsWith(WATCH_FILE_NAME)) {
                        System.out.println("Volume.txt was changed");
                    }
                }

                if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                    System.out.println("Key invalid");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops, something is not working");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code may actually prove useful for my project. Currently the project just reads text/csv files from input stream. Should I replace this all with a FileSystem structure?